# How to get the ID of the max value while using Summarize

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a calculated field in Excel's PowerPivot and am having trouble getting the results I want. Specifically, I'm trying to get the name of the item with the highest value from a subsequent column in the results of a summarize or groupby clause.

**Sample Data:**

[image: Sample Data:]

The calculation is a two step process:

1. Sum the # of Hours by Project
2. Return the Name/ID of the project with the highest sum

In this example, the final result should be "D", as "D"s Sum of Hours is the highest (10).

I'm able to determine the highest number of hours using this calculated field:

`Test:=MAXX(Summarize(ExampleTable, [Project], "TotalHours", Sum([Hours])), [TotalHours])`

I'm not sure how to either adjust this calculated field or create a new calculated field to return "D".

Further complicating things, the results must take the current filter context into example, so that the results are always correct no matter what the user does. Here's a more robust set of sample data and expected results:

[image: Complicated Example]

Here are the expected results in terms of hours. For each yellow cell, I want the result of the calculated field to be the name of the project (A-E).

[image: Expected results]

Here's an example of an actual report showing the MaxHours instead of the project name. My goal is to show Project Name instead of MaxHours. (Feel free to ignore the subtotals).

[image: Sample Report]

`MaxHours:=MAXX(SUMMARIZE(Table1,[Project],"Total Hours",sum([Hours])),[Total Hours])`

Here's the example results without subtotals:

[image: Sample results]

NOTE: We can assume no ties for the purpose of this question.

Comment: In that pivot table that you shared, it seems like you are already using "Project" as a row dimension. Did you mean to group by something else? For example in row 4, you have project D, so how will the values be anything else but project D?

Comment: @RedVII - good question. I'm using "Project" as the row dimension ONLY to illustrate the desired results. The final report would NOT have Project in the PivotTable...just the other dimensions. Does that make sense. If helpful, I can post an image of that as well (since I'm able to calculate the desired hours, just not the Project)

Comment: Gotcha, I think I see what you meant. I'll post my attempt in a bit.

Comment: Thanks @RedVII - I've updated the question with some more images that should hopefully help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to determine the project with the maximum number of hours can be done using built in tools in Pivot tables, like top N or sortings.

However this solution is calculated purely using DAX.

First create a **calculated column**:

```
Rank =
RANKX (
    ExampleTable,
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( ExampleTable[Hours] ),
        FILTER ( ExampleTable, [Project] = EARLIER ( ExampleTable[Project] ) )
    ),
    ,
    ,
    DENSE
)
```

Then use that column to determine the Project Id/Name by creating a **measure**:

```
Max Hours Project =
CALCULATE (
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( ExampleTable[Project], 0 ),
    FILTER ( ExampleTable, [Rank] = 1 )
)
```

In this case I used `FIRSTNONBLANK` function because the name of the project in your example is type Text. If it is a number actually you can replace it by `MAX` function instead.

Also note a calculated column is different to a measure, both are calculations performed in a different scope. calculated columns are perfomed by each row while measures can be perfomed over a set of rows.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great answer, you did it much more simply than I was about to approach it!

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestions, however I don't believe that this works because the rank should change based on the current filter context. Using a calculated column doesn't allow that to happen. I'll update my original question to include an example of how this impacts things. Additionally, I can't use the native PivotTable capabilities (e.g. sorting) because this needs to be included in a larger report.

Comment: @RedVII, Unfortunately the initial version of the OP was very short about the complete requeriments. You approached it in the right way too, TOPN function came to my mind but I did not materialize it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's my solution pictured below. It seems to work. Note that there ARE ties in this data (for example, Dog and Bar have ties between A and C, so it picked A) but you should hopefully not have that problem in your real dataset.

[image]

Solution:

1) Create a measure, I called it "Hours Total". It's important to specify ALLEXCEPT() for all fields that you want to be able to drill this by (in this case, it will be "Person" and "Type":

```
CALCULATE(SUM([Hours]),ALLEXCEPT(ExampleTable,ExampleTable[Project],ExampleTable[Person],ExampleTable[Type]))
```

2) Create a measure, I called it "Top Project". This measures simply calculates the top project using the TOPN() function, using the previous measure. In case of ties, I wrapped FIRSTNONBLANK() around it.

```
=FIRSTNONBLANK(TOPN(1,VALUES(ExampleTable[Project]),[Hours Total]),1)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is a great option, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without having to specify all of the possible dimensions, as that may not be viable? I'm trying to do something like this: https://www.powerpivotpro.com/2012/06/top-selling-product-using-firstnonblank/ except that the VALUES() piece of it needs to come from something like a SUMMARIZE/CALCULATETABLE/GROUPBY instead of from the raw data itself. We can ignore the problems created by ties.

Comment: Hmm, you know in this case, if I change that first measure to simply be SUM([Hours]) then it still works exactly the same, because in this case the ALLEXCEPT() is not even necessary since the Hours are being cut by all the dimensions that we care about. So possibly you can get away with not using ALLEXCEPT. Unfortunately this is where my knowledge hits an end too, I've really wanted to not have to specify a bunch of columns in some queries but as of yet, I'm not aware of a workaround.